# Exactly which variables need to be sig_atomic_t in the context of signal handling?

Tags: c, signals, sig-atomic-t

Here is a simple toy program that uses `volatile sig_atomic_t`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define UNUSED(x) (void) (x)

volatile sig_atomic_t quit;

void sigusr1_handler(int sig)
{
    UNUSED(sig);
    write(1, "handler\n", 8);
    quit = 1;
}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction sa;

    sa.sa_handler = sigusr1_handler;
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);

    if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        return 1;
    }

    quit = 0;
    while (!quit)
        ;

    printf("Exiting ...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I think I know why `volatile sig_atomic_t` is necessary for the `quit` variable in this particular program.

1. Without `volatile`, the compiler may optimize `while (!quit) ;` to an infinite loop. It does not find the loop modifying `quit`, so it assumes that `quit` always remains `0`.
2. An update to `quit` or a read of `quit` should happen in a single machine instruction. If it takes multiple machine instructions to update or read `quit`, then if a signal handler is invoked while an update was going on, a read in the signal handler may see inconsistent value in `quit`.

Am I correct so far? If not, please correct me in your answer.

Now I want to learn a generalized rule for when `sig_atomic_t` is necessary in the context of signal handling. Jonathan Leffler has explained in the comment that it is not easy to provide a generalization.

Can you provide a list of known scenarios where a variable needs to be defined as `sig_atomic_t` from C standard perspective? It need not be an exhaustive list. It could be a list a less experienced developer can refer to while writing C software with signal handling code.

Comment: 'Generalization' is not easy; the semantics of signal handling are different on different machines.  The C standard is incredibly restrictive about what you can do in a signal handler.  POSIX is a lot more generous, but there are still severe limits (for example, `strlen()` can't be used safely, but `write()` can).  The rules on Windows are probably different again. Are you planning to use `sigaction()` or `signal()` or some other API?  Regarding point (1), "yes"; point (2) "more or less" (near enough not to matter).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the comment. I have narrowed down the scope of the question to: (1) asking for a list of known scenarios (need not be an exhaustive list) where a variable needs to be defined as `sig_atomic_t` (2) asking for the answer that holds good for the C standard (not POSIX).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you provide a list of known scenarios where a variable needs to be defined as `sig_atomic_t` from C standard perspective?

There are 2 relevant sections from the [c99 spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> (§7.14 p2)
>   [The `sig_atomic_t` type] is the (possibly volatile-qualified) integer type of an object that can be accessed as an atomic entity, even in the presence of asynchronous interrupts
>
> (§7.14.1.1 p5)
>   If the signal occurs other than as the result of calling the `abort` or `raise` function, the behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to any object with static storage duration other than by assigning a value to an object declared as `volatile sig_atomic_t`, ...

"Static storage duration" is defined as:

> (§6.2.4 p3)
>   An object whose identifier is declared with external or internal linkage, or with the storage-class specifier `static` has *static storage duration*. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.

In a nutshell, you are required to use `volatile sig_atomic_t` if the variable may be accessed asynchronously (i.e., the variable is accessed both inside and outside of the signal handler). In addition, it is undefined behavior to access a non-`volatile sig_atomic_t` variable which has static storage duration. Undefined behavior means that not only could the value of the variable be inconsistent, the program could do something else entirely (like segfault).